# Unable to get subsites of sharepoint web applicaton

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint web application, with two subsites "test1" and "test2".

The addresses are the next:

http://www05:48042

http://www05:48042/sites/test1

http://www05:48042/sites/test2

```
var context = new ClientContext(string.Format("http://{0}", "www05:48042"));
```

`context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credentials.Login,`

```
credentials.Password);
var sites = context.Web.Webs;
context.Load(sites);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Login and password are correct. However, I am always getting an empty collection in webs, but should get at least 2 elements. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code snippet below:

```
   public static void getSubWebs(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(path);
                Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(oWebsite, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Web orWebsite in oWebsite.Webs)
                {
                    string newpath = mainpath + orWebsite.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    getSubWebs(newpath);
                    Console.WriteLine(newpath + "\n" + orWebsite.Title);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

 static string mainpath = "http://sp:80/";
 getSubWebs(mainpath);
 Console.Read();
```

[image]